Is tk.Frame() and Frame() the same thing?
I was wondering if tk.Frame() and Frame() the same thing because the tutorial online i saw on Youtube uses tk.Frame() while my teacher uses Frame() for creating a gui.
I am curious if it affects anything if they are different.
